# PowerMock expectNew how to specify the type of the parameters

Tags: junit, powermock

When I use PowerMock to mock the constructor,I want to specify the type of the paremeters. I use the method

```
PowerMock.expectNew(Class<T> type, Class<?>[] parameterTypes, Object... arguments)
```

If I want to specify the `String` type, what shoud I fill in the `parameterTypes`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Given these example classes:

```
public class MyClass {
    public MyClass(String theParam) {
        //Some interesting code...
    }
}

public class MyFactory {
    public MyClass createMyClass() {
        return new MyClass("foo");
    }
}
```

Then you would do an `expectNew` as follows:

```
public class MyFactoryTest {
    @Test
    public void testCreateMyClass() {
        //...

        PowerMock.expectNew(MyClass.class, new Class[] {String.class}, "foo");

        //...
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks very much,It's very useful.But I'm sorry i can't vote up beacuse of the low reputation.

Comment: As the author of the question, you can still accept the answer. :-)

Comment: hello ,it's me again.when i use Whitebox.invokeConstructor(),what shou I do to specify the parameters' type

Comment: Read the docs: http://powermock.googlecode.com/svn/docs/powermock-1.5.1/apidocs/org/powermock/reflect/Whitebox.html#invokeConstructor(java.lang.Class, java.lang.Class[], java.lang.Object[]). It has a similar signature to expectNew(). But that's really a different question.